# How to run v1/eval endpoint with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bash, curl, marklogic

I'd like to run a JS sample provided by a third party using the `/v1/eval` endpoint. However, JS has a few idiosyncrasies that need to be fixed before it can be used. Here is an example:

The following script fails `curl -X POST -d @script.sjs http://host:8000/v1/eval` where `script.sjs` contains:

```
javascript=
// Please execute this modified query for me ...
const addNumbers = (a, b) => {
  console.log(`Adding ${a} + ${b}`)
  return a + b
}
addNumbers(2, 3)
```

When sent over curl the script is interpreted as one line so a lot of things go wrong:

- Single line comments don't work
- All lines must be ended with semi colon (users may not provide them)
- Some characters aren't accepted despite Marklogic supporting full ES6

  - e.g. fat arrow (`=>` and `+`) from above example fail.

Therefore, to get the script running I need to heavily modify the script as follows:

```
javascript=
/* Please execute this query for me */
function multiplyNumbers (a, b) {
    console.log(`Adding ${a} + ${b}`);
    return a * b
}
multiplyNumbers(2, 3);
```

**Is there any curl setting that could prevent the data getting "corrupted"?**

or

**Is there a away to modify the script contents using bash so that it can be interpreted correctly by the `/v1/eval` endpoint?**

Comment: Suggest that you also tag this as cURL.  Running your example through postman following the requirements of the endpoint (x-www-form-urlencoded, javascript form data etc) works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `javascript=` from the SJS module and have it just be the code. Then send the content of the SJS module as the `javascript` param and use the [`--data-urlencode`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) option instead of [`-d`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) to have curl urlencode the content of the file, rather than having to worry about reformatting or urlencoding the content.

`curl --anyauth -i -X POST --data-urlencode javascript@script.sjs http://localhost:8000/v1/eval`